# Java scanner.nextLine() not reading long line with 259094 characters

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to read an xml file as a String in Java so that I can encrypt it.

My current approach is to treat it like a txt file.

My problem is that the third line in the xml file is 259094 characters long and for some reason, the scanner's nextLine() method is only reading up to 131072 characters into the string instead of the whole line. My code for reading the xml file is below and [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xT0gX3nk_ectknDmGHqPRFqdL3Nd1xas/view?usp=sharing) is the xml file I used.

```
try {
  File myFile = new File(filename);
  Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myFile);
  int lineCount = 0;

  while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
    if (lineCount > 0) { // To make sure it doesn't append \n before the first line[enter link description here][1]
      data += "\n";
    }
    String temp = myReader.nextLine();
    data += temp;
    lineCount += 1;
  }
      
  myReader.close();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.out.println("An error occurred.");
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The xml file has had its whitespace stripped on save. (No carriage returns in the content after the xml and microsoft declarations on line 0 and 1). So, yeah... that one line holding all of the xml content is going to blow up your scanner. You'll need to load this in with a stream and encrypt it in chunks.

Comment: I read successfully the file. The third line has 259094 characters. Is there any error occurred or the third line contains a space after 131072 characters?

Comment: Isn't it just reasonable to read from an input stream (whatever it comes from, say your XML file), and write to an encrypted output stream (whatever it goes to)?

Comment: What fluffy wrote will solve another problem: there are many "kind" of line separators supported by `Scanner.nexLine()` (by taking a look at the source code I see a regular expression like `\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085]`, so a total of 6 different line separators). You are replacing all of them with `\n` creating a "different file" that you are then hashing.

Comment: Why use Scanner (which basically exists to parse input) to do something as simple as reading an entire file (which needs no parsing)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided works fine on my system.

But if your aim is to encrypt a file (without parsing it), then there is no reason why you should read it as a String. You could just treat it as a byte stream and encrypt those.

An example for that would be the following code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
            String filename = "/tmp/xml.xml";
    
            KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            keygen.init(256);
            SecretKey secretKey = keygen.generateKey();
            byte[] IV = new byte[16]; //TODO The bytes should be random and different for each file
            GCMParameterSpec gcmSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, IV);
    
            try {
                encryptFile(new File(filename), new File(filename + ".encrypted"), secretKey, gcmSpec);
                decyptFile(new File(filename + ".encrypted"), new File(filename + ".decrypted"), secretKey, gcmSpec);
            } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
    
        }
    
        static void encryptFile(File inputFile, File outputFile, SecretKey secretKey, GCMParameterSpec gcmSpec) throws InvalidKeyException, IOException {
            InputStream input = null;
            OutputStream output = null;
            try {
                input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
                output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/PKCS5Padding");
    
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, gcmSpec);
    
                while (input.available() > 0) {
                    byte[] bytes = input.readNBytes(128);
                    output.write(cipher.update(bytes));
                }
                output.write(cipher.doFinal());
    
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            } finally {
                if (input != null) input.close();
                if (output != null) output.close();
            }
        }
    
        static void decyptFile(File encryptedFile, File outputFile, SecretKey secretKey, GCMParameterSpec gcmSpec) throws InvalidKeyException, IOException {
            InputStream input = null;
            OutputStream output = null;
            try {
                input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(encryptedFile));
                output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/PKCS5Padding");
    
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, gcmSpec);
    
                while (input.available() > 0) {
                    byte[] bytes = input.readNBytes(128);
                    output.write(cipher.update(bytes));
                }
    
                output.write(cipher.doFinal());
    
            } catch (NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (input != null) input.close();
                if (output != null) output.close();
            }
        }
```

This reads a file and saves the output to another file. Note that for this to be secure you need to change the IV to a random value with changes for each file (Probably by saving the iv at the beginning of the encrypted file)

Comment: Thanks I will look into your second point. However, I clearly provided an example file with the google drive link. Maybe read my whole question before replying/downvoting?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the example file.

Comment: no worries, I read some of the comments above and the code seems to work fine on some other systems as well. some other guys also had a similar suggestion as you and i'll definitely try it out when I get back. thanks so much :)

Comment: thanks to piliko here and everyone who recommended a similar solution using InputStream. I can confirm that it works